# Where to find the ISR called by the linux kernel when a keyboard button is pressed?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, interrupt, interrupt-handling

Where in the linux kernel can I find the ISR called by the kernel when a keyboard button is pressed?

Apparently there a hardcoded IRQ numbers, keyboard seems to have the 1 whereas touchpad/mouse has the 12, where to find these in kernel source code?

I know I could probably spend hours to search for this myself, but maybe a more experienced kernel hacker might speed this up.

Comment: Do you still have a PS/2 keyboard, or are you using a USB one?  In the latter case things will be a bit more abstract.  Unless the goal of your question is curiosity (which would be fine) you may want to concentrate more on what you hope to achieve, as there are probably better ways.

Comment: I'm using a USB keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The actual IRQ numbers would depend on architecture. Your example numbers seem to match x86:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_request_%28PC_architecture%29#x86_IRQs

(It also says "On Linux, IRQ mappings can be viewed by executing `cat /proc/interrupts` or using the `procinfo` utility.")